# EF Code First Foreign Key Association Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, code-first

Ok I want to know if there is a way to map foreign key relationships with EF Code First Data Annotations instead of using the Fluent API when the names don't match. Here is my scenario.
I have two tables with a one-many relationship with a foreign key.

A Security table with:
  int SecurityID (PK)
  //Other columns
  int IncomeFrequencyID (FK)

A Frequency table with
  int FrequencyID (PK)
  //Other columns

So IncomeFrequencyID maps to FrequencyID

Then in my Code First:

```
public class Security
{
    public int SecurityID {get;set;}
    //Other properties
    public int IncomeFrequencyID {get;set;}

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual Frequency IncomeFrequency {get;set;}
}

public class Frequency
{
    public int FreqencyID {get;set;}
    //Other properties
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish the EF relationship using Data Annotations?
Maybe using the [AssociationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associationattribute(v=vs.95).aspx)?

```
[Association("FK_Security_Frequency", "IncomeFrequencyID", "FrequencyID", IsForeignKey = true)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ForeignKey` attribute, for example:

```
public class Security
{
    public int SecurityID {get;set;}
    //Other properties
    public int IncomeFrequencyID {get;set;}

    //Navigation Properties
    [ForeignKey("IncomeFrequencyID")]
    public virtual Frequency IncomeFrequency {get;set;}
}
```

And on the other side, mark it as a primary key:

```
public class Frequency
{
    [Key]
    public int FreqencyID {get;set;}
    //Other properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Much easier than I thought.